# Assembly directives vs. assembler flags to specify the same thing, like .thumb vs. -mthumb?

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu-assembler

I've recently started learning some ARM assembly. However, I'm not exactly sure I understand the difference between assembly directives and their assembler flag counterparts. I'm using the arm-none-eabi-as assembler.

In other words, is the `.cpu cortex-m4` assembly directive equivalent to the `-mcpu=cortex-m4` assembler flag (or `.fpu softvfp` vs. `-mfpu=softvfp`, or `.thumb` vs `-mthumb`)? I've noticed that the STM32 Cube IDE includes both the directive and the flag when generating code. Is this how it is supposed to be, or should there be only one (either the directive or the flag)?

Comment: Please refer to [the manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Directives.html#ARM-Directives) where it says that the directives do the same thing as the options.

Comment: this was programmer specific or because this was part of a larger project with multiple developers. not something uncommon, not something unexpected.  .thumb , imo should be in the code.  .cpu vs -mcpu that is something that could be either or or both in case one or the other programmer is paranoid

Comment: you do run into the risk of problems if one is allowed to generate armv7-m instructions but the build can made for an armv6-m which would happen from the .cpu.